# Error React Native > Could not find method provided() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+]

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I npm install react-native-video-player after then, When I restarted the application, I encountered this error

BU�LD FAILED in 23s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8082

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\zekican.aydin\test\psikoyorum-mobile\node_modules\react-native-video\android\build.gradle' line: 20
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-video'.

> Could not find method provided() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 23s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\zekican.aydin\test\psikoyorum-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\zekican.aydin\test\psikoyorum-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\zekican.aydin\test\psikoyorum-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\zekican.aydin\test\psikoyorum-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

Comment: Any workaround?